# FancyBox not working inside an ajax loaded DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I've seen a couple of other issues like this and read through them but still couldn't solve my problem.

I have some DIVs loaded through ajax on a page, within one of which are links that I want to open with Fancybox. Strangely, if I open the DIV with the Fancybox link in FIRST, it works fine. However if I open any of the other DIVs, then open the one with the Fancybox link, it doesn't work.

Similarly, if I open the Fancybox DIV, then another, then go back, it doesn't work.

```
$("a.result").fancybox({'transitionIn':'fade'});
```

That's all I have at the bottom of the DIV with the Fancybox links. I originally tried with document.ready() too, but it's just the same...

Any ideas what I should be doing?

Comment: Are the DIVs in the DOM when you make the fancybox() call?  Could you post some small snippets of your code?

Comment: `<div class="section navigate">
 <div rel="tips">Your Tips</div>
 <div rel="results">Your Results</div>
 <div rel="details">Your Details</div>
</div>`

`<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("div.navigate div").click(function(){
  var pageToLoad=$(this).attr("rel");
  $("#pageload").html("<p>Loading...</p>");
  $("#pageload").load("/content/user/"+pageToLoad+".php");
 });
});
</script>`

The Fancybox call is in results.php.

Comment: Hmm...I thought `` made things into code, obviously not :/

Answer (score 2):

By replacing the DIV you're removing the original element that had the Fancybox event attached to it. If you call `$("a.result").fancybox({'transitionIn':'fade'});` in the success function of your ajax call it will re-attach the events and the Fancybox should load.

Comment: Actually, silly me. There is no Ajax involved in this, I had gotten confused with another page on the site. It's just a straight .load()

Presumably though, the same applies? Where should I add the call to fancybox()?

Comment: Great! Fancybox load after Ajax call.